# Get the inputs form with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

If I have an input, and want to get its form, in plain-js, you can use `emailinput.form`, but to do that with jquery-objects, it's get messy: `$(emailinput[0].form)`, other recommendable to use `emailinput.closest('form')`, and it work's on normal pages, but if someone uses the inputs attribute "form", that thus two return different results.

https://jsfiddle.net/nzh43dcz/

So is `$(emailinput[0].form)` the best way to go, or is there some other jquery-ways to get the form?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't need to wrap `c` (in the fiddle) to then unwrap it, you've effectively done:  `$($(c)[0].form)` - so just `$(c.form)`.   Personally, I'd go with `$(c).closest("form")`.   I'm not sure what you mean by "if someone uses the inputs attributes "form"".

Comment: why not use `.parent` or `.parents` ? `$('#jquery_1').html ( "selected form " + $(c).parent("form").attr("id") );`

Comment: I have hard time trying to understand what this phrase mean "but if someone uses the inputs attribute "form" ". luckily it's not only me :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [input.form](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) attribute from the input is probably the best. I don't really see where it gets messy? In your fiddle you could replace

```
$('#jquery_2').html('core-js form: ' + $(jc[0].form).attr('id'));
```

with

```
$("#jquery_3").html('core-js form: ' + $(c.form).attr("id"));
```

Which is much cleaner and isn't 'messy'. You can always wrap DOM elements inside jQuery to get a jQuery object.

In your fiddle `var jc = $(c);` is not necessary.

I hope this helps

Comment: Yes but what you are trying to achieve is to get the form enclosing the input you passed as a parameter to the `window.i` method aren't you? If so, you don't need jQuery to get the enclosing form, vanilla JS will do the work for you, using the `.form` attribute. You can then use `$(input.form)` to get a jQuery object of the form so that you can call `.attr("id")` on it.